# How to set single VoiceOver for group of UIControls

Tags: voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have a `UIButton` and a `UILabel` embedded in a `UIStackView`, which looks something like this in Interface Builder:

[image]

By setting the `UIStackView`'s `isAccessibilityElement` and `accessibilityLabel` properties, I have been able to group the `UIButton` and `UILabel` into a single VoiceOver grouping, similar to this:

[image]

However with this configuration, the `UIButton` (gray circle in the image above) becomes untappable, rendering the control useless.

Is there a way to maintain this grouping while still allowing the `UIButton` to be tappable?

Comment: What did you do to group the button and the label?

Comment: Hi @DavidRönnqvist, I've updated the question in answer to yours. Thanks.

Comment: @Marco : to complete the excellent answer of David Rônnqvist, take a look at http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#grouping-elements to get some code snippets (Objc + Swift) dealing with your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the [`accessibilityActivationPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615179-accessibilityactivationpoint) for an accessibility element is the midpoint of its frame. When the button and the label got grouped into a new element the midpoint of their combined frame is no longer in the bounds of the button.

You can fix this by overriding the stack view's `accessibilityActivationPoint` so that it returns the activation point of the button instead. Note that this property is in screen coordinates, so if the view moves on screen (for example scrolls) then it won't be enough to just set it once.

---

Also, for the grouped element to "behave" like a button to users of assistive technologies you should give it the [`accessibilityTraits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615202-accessibilitytraits) of a button. A complete list of all can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibility/accessibility_traits).

Comment: Awesome answer.